# Custom field not editable by the user

Tags: customization

I have a custom field. The field is visible and editable by the user, moreover I also view it in the user table on the administrator side.

If I want to make this field uneditable for the user (but visible) what can I do?

I don't want to use plugins like adf or similar

```
function my_new_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
    //add Nickname Telegram
    $contactmethods['telegram'] = 'Nickname Telegram';
    //$contactmethods['subscription'] = 'Subscription until';
    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_new_contactmethods',10,1);
add_filter('user_contactmethods','hide_profile_fields',10,1);


function new_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['telegram'] = 'Telegram';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );

function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'telegram' :
            return get_the_author_meta( 'telegram', $user_id );
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

Edit : add screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is the code to add a custom field if you are not using ACF? Details are necessary on this hook `user_contactmethods`.

Comment: I specified that I don't want to use plugins like AFC

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to insert some custom javascript in WP Admin. You can target the field by its ID, then just add the `disabled` attribute to the input. The user will be able to see it, but not change it.

Obviously you'll have to use an if statement to allow you to edit it as an administrator but disable it for the user.

Comment: do you have a reference link to understand how I can do it? I'm not very practical

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of what the field looks like and where it needs to be disabled or enabled? I can create a code snippet for you after that.